# Upgrade from Axis 1.62 to Axis 1.79 and disable SOAPAction validation

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I am novice on AXIS framework and handling a legacy support product.

While I upgraded one of my service from Axis 1.62 to Axis 1.79. Service started giving error only on higher prod. it is works fine on dev and QA environment.

I am able to browse to WSDL in all cases. While on prod it is giving below error when I hit service using postman:

The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://127.0.0.1:9080/Import/services/ImportService and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

And on prod environment when I provide SOAPAction header on postman it works as expected. So I am not able to understand why same code with same version of Axis works on lower environment while without SOAPAction header and gives error on Prod?

Can we disable SOAPAction validation, it will break huge number of clients. I tried adding SOAPAction header using ServletFilter but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.